# translate directive not work in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, ngx-translate, ng-upgrade, angular-gettext

I'm currently working on an angular hybrib app (angular + angularJs). 
The app use angular-gettext and ngx-translate for translation.
Both work in their own runtime but I can't make it work when I downgrade an Angular component into an angularJs one.
I wonder if there is a mismatch between the two `translate` directives ?

Comment: Please provide some code examples to determine what is the problem.

Comment: Hi Mario, there was no problem, the main problem come from that json generated by both tools haven't the same structure. angular-gettext-tool generate a file wrap translations in an object with the lang as the key. I've made plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/JkQBPIs4ONcEZWKH7BQS?p=preview

Comment: Can't figure it out. Hope someone joins discussion

Comment: I mean the problem come from how translation are used. I mean, angular-gettext need a json ` {fr: {"hello": "Salut"}}`where ngx-translate need a flat json structure ( {"hello": "Bonjour"} but since I use the same i18n json file from in angular / angularJs I wasn't able to found translation in my angular component